# When should I use the destroy method?

Tags: javascript, destructor

I made a [small javascript framework](https://github.com/LeMisterV/EasyPrototype) designed to add some useful stuff in the prototyped object model (super method call, inheritance, auto init...).

In this framework, some object methods are automatically called, like "init" to construct the object and "destroy" on window unload.

I have two questions about this destroy method :

- What is this method used for?

I think it should do some cleaning on DOM objects (unbind events), but is there other cleaning to do?

- Should this method be called on another event? Is it possible to detect when an object is destroyed and call this method at this time?

If anyone is interested in this framework, I posted it on gitHub, but right now there's no documentation :-/ :
https://github.com/LeMisterV/EasyPrototype

Comment: Destroy is called on unload? Well, than the method can do ANYTHING - since it won't have any impact on anything else. After all, the browser is about to navigate away from that page anyway. Destroy methods make sense for components destroyed during the lifetime of the webpage. There is nothing to clean up on "unload" for a webapp, unlike for desktop apps, which use the opportunity to write buffers to disk, release file handles, etc.

Comment: In Javascript it is not possible to write a method that gets called automatically when/before an object is "destroyed", it has to be called explicitly. What does "destroy" mean anyway in JS? When the object is garbage-collected - which is random? When the last handle to it is released?

Comment: I suspect that @Nicolas is worried about memory leaks in IE, which has problems when DOM elements have properties whose values are JavaScript objects, esp. closures. The DOM memory manager doesn't know how to reclaim that space so it doesn't.

Comment: @Pointy: There are no mem leaks on UNLOAD even in IE, and generally, destroy() is good to do in other browsers as well - if a component is destroyed during the lifetime of a page (some apps don't use show/hide for widgets but do a new Widget()/widget.destroy() cycle each time).

Comment: @Mörre I think that IE6 definitely had problems with circular references that would not be freed for the life of the browser process. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448(v=vs.85).aspx) is a write-up from Microsoft, and there are many others available describing the problem.

Comment: @Mörre: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929874 *"When you use Microsoft Internet Explorer 6 on a Microsoft Windows XP-based computer to view a Web page that uses JScript scripting code, a memory leak occurs in Internet Explorer. When you visit a different Web page, the leaked memory is not released."*

Comment: So it's as I said, only IE 6. So who cares? Seriously, I'm all for PUNISHING people still using IE 6 :)
Of course, it's better to simply refuse to run and tell the user to upgrade instead of introducing silent bugs. In any case no argument for destroy in THIS case - in other comments I give specific examples for when it's useful (regardless of browser, as tool of JS web programming).

Comment: @Morre: Microsoft released a fix but it didn't completely fix it, apparently. There's more to the story than just that support article.

Comment: So anyway, re-reading the original Q, it seems it has been answered throughly - unbind all events.

Answer (score 3):

A better question, why do you need to destroy anything? if the window is unloading, everything will be garbage collected on your behalf.

Comment: There is no garbage collection necessary, which can be a quite expensive process - the entire memory can just be released. GC is a process happening during runtime of an app, and (usually) only if it's really necessary (since it is not "free" to run GC)

Comment: There's a huge difference between theory and practice here. It's a lot more complicated than that when you start taking history navigation and saving state. Things don't get immediately GC'd. Also, you and I know that everything should be GC'd on unload, but in IE at least, that's not a guarantee.

Comment: That GC bug affects only IE 6. You can argue that there are programmers who still care - but please.... and I'm not sure I ever heard it affects it even when LEAVING a page - would you have a reference for that?

Comment: See my comments for the question above.

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of Internet Explorer get stuck on circular references between JavaScript and the DOM, since they are garbage collected separately. This tends to be an issue when you start adding event handlers to everything.

What you should do in your framework is keep track of every time you add an event so that you can go through that array of events and destroy each of them on unload.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which versions of IE have this problem? and do other major frameworks manually track added event handlers?

Comment: Because it's not guaranteed to happen automatically for you in some browsers, so you're working around their memory leaks.

Comment: IE6 has that issue. If anyone claims other browsers I'd like to see references.

Comment: @Thr4wn: Up to at least IE7. jQuery handles it more gracefully than I would have. You can see it in the jQuery.event.add function, starting on line 2515 of jquery 1.6.1

Comment: Just to clarify, IE7 _does_ has a memory leak problem? Or are saying IE versions strictly less than 7?

Answer (score 1):

First, and foremost, the reason for a "destroy" (or any destructor) is to bring your "system" or program into a known stable state. In browsers, all memory usage (which is the classic issue) is automatically done for you with [Garbage Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29).

So the only reason left why you might want a destructor ("destroy" method) is if there are abstract properties about your system that the object needs to ensure is in a known state.

Comment: Not quite. Example: If an app is written to use "btn = new Button()" and "btn.destroy()" instead of creating the button and then use hide()/show() on it destroy() is quite necessary. It removes the DOM element(s) for the widget, doing the equivalent of hide(). That is legit programming, even though I usually prefer to instantiate only once.

Comment: would that example not fit in my description? Or should I adjust my explanation. Having a loose button hanging around in the DOM is what I would consider "Unstable" and therefore does indeed suggest a need of a destructor. I guess "removing leftovers" is a better general description of destructors than "making system stable"

Comment: Your description as I read it is not wring of course, but for stuff like "write unsaved buffers to disk" in a desktop app. To do hide/show type programming is something else, yours seems to be more for "internal issues" while this is for "deliberate external user-targeted effects".